# Creating funcion for short date in spanish

Tags: mysql, function

Hi guys this function gives me this error: "Something wrong in line 35." (RETURN diaCompleto;), I dont know whats wrong with the code below anyway can point me out in the correct direction, tyvm.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION DIA_FECHA(fecha date) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8)
BEGIN

  DECLARE nomDia VARCHAR(6);
  DECLARE dia VARCHAR(2);
  DECLARE diaCompleto VARCHAR(8);

  SET dia = LPAD(DAY(fecha),2,'0');

  IF(DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 1) THEN
    SET nomDia = 'DOM - ';

  IF(DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 2) THEN
    SET nomDia = 'LUN - ';

  IF(DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 3) THEN
    SET nomDia = 'MAR - ';

  IF(DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 4) THEN
    SET nomDia = 'MIE - ';

  IF(DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 5) THEN
    SET nomDia = 'JUE - ';

  IF(DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 6) THEN
    SET nomDia = 'VIE - ';

  IF(DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 7) THEN
    SET nomDia = 'SAB - ';

  SET diaCompleto = CONCAT(nomDia,dia);
  RETURN diaCompleto;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your syntax error is that you need to use `END IF;` after each `IF/THEN`. See examples in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

I think you don't need to write this function at all. Instead, you could use MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). It supports locale-aware names for days of the week.

```
mysql> set lc_time_names = 'es_ES';

mysql> select date_format(curdate(), '%a - %d') as diaCompleto;
+-------------+
| diaCompleto |
+-------------+
| sáb - 19    |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bill, Ill use your native mysql solution!

Comment: I've been using MySQL for over 20 years. Number of times I've had to write a stored function: 0.